# Recognizing multiple keyphrases in CMUSphinx for Android

Tags: cmusphinx

I am able to recognize one keyphrase by adding it in the code. However, I am unable to add multiple keyphrases. Some of the posts mention adding the keyphrases to a file.  I am not able to find an example of code  where multiple keyphrases are used.

Can someone point me to a post or guide me to get this done?
Thanks

Ram

Comment: Example code is provided in the linked question

Comment: Thanks.. In  "oh mighty computer /1e-40/", what does /1e-40/ represent? How do I decide what to use for other phrases?  Could not find an explanation in CMU documentation.

Comment: Threshold selection process is explained in tutorial http://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutoriallm

Comment: Thanks.  I notice Pocketsphinx is only supported on Android. Any chance it will be supported on IOS platforms?

Comment: Google for tlsphinx

Comment: Thanks got that.. In the Android demo, the is KWS_SEARCH set to "wakeup".  The KWS_SEARCH is used in switchsearch().  What is the purpose of the "wakeup"?

Comment: The name of the search

Comment: This is my keyphrases file content   :help /1e-1/
help me /1e-10/
please help me /1e-60/
oh mighty computer/1e-40/
someone help me /1e-30/
tiger help me /1e-30/

Comment: I created a myphrases file with 5 lines of keyphrases.  Created file descriptor "keyphrases" to use with recognizer.addKeywordSearch (KWS_SEARCH,keyphrases). My KWS_SEARCH = "tiger" and my KEYPHRASE = "tiger help me".  I built it and ran, but it is very iffy. SOmetimes it picks up the phrase sometimes not.  How do i show the code? It is a simplified version of the demo.

Comment: Here is the list of phrases <br/> `help /1e-1/
help me /1e-10/
please help me /1e-60/
oh mighty computer/1e-40/
someone help me /1e-30/
tiger help me /1e-30/`

Comment: You can test detection properties using audio file. Good audio quality is critical.

Comment: Ok. I made this work by using the digits menu and using my phrases and my key word. For simple phrases it works well.  Couple of questions: (1) How can I make this work in the background with home screen locked. I would like to say words without having to touch the phone.  (2) The response times s are very random. For the same set of phrases by the same speaker, sometimes they are instantaneous and other times it takes several attempts to respond to keyword/keyphrase? Any way to improve the response?